# could not able to spawn(ssh) using expect

Tags: tcl, expect, spawn

while executing

```
$expect filename.exp user pwd ip
```

I got the error

> could not execute "ssh -l user ip": no such file or directory

The contents of `filename.exp` are this:

```
#!/opt/sfw/bin/expect -D

set OMC_Usr  [lindex $argv 0]
set OMC_Pwd  [lindex $argv 1]
set OMC_IP  [lindex $argv 2]

set cmd "ssh -l $OMC_Usr $OMC_IP"
spawn $cmd
expect "Password:"
send "$OMC_Pwd\r"
interact
```

help me to proceed
Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `spawn` needs the command and its arguments passed to it as multiple Tcl arguments, just like the standard Tcl `exec` command. The fix is to do this directly:

```
spawn ssh -l $OMC_Usr $OMC_IP
```

Or, if you prefer (and you've got Tcl 8.5):

```
set cmd "ssh -l $OMC_Usr $OMC_IP"
spawn {*}$cmd
```

Or, if you've got 8.4 or before:

```
eval spawn [lrange $cmd 0 end]
```

But ***don't*** do this:

```
eval spawn $cmd
```

because that will break unexpectedly if you have a Tcl metacharacter in the username (or IP address, but that's very unlikely).

---

Of course, the *real* fix is to set up an RSA keypair and use `ssh-agent` to manage it. Like that, you won't need to pass passwords on any command line; that's important because the command line of a process is public information about the process. Really. You can find it out with something trivial like `ps -efww` (or the equivalent for your OS). Environment variables are just as insecure too; there's an option to `ps` to show them too.