# script to ssh to a unix server

Tags: automation, ssh, connection, tcl, sh

It will be helpful if somebody could tell me how to connect to a unix server using username and password as arguments.my username and password is "anitha".

How can i create a shell script which automatically connect to my unix server with this username and password?

Comment: Connect? How do you want to connect? http? ssh? ...? If you want to open a ssh connection don't use name/passwd but [ssh keys](http://pkeck.myweb.uga.edu/ssh/) instead.

Answer (score 5):

I guess you want to remotely connect to your *nix server from network. Base on my guess, to:

- connect to remote *nix server, everybody is using [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell)

  `ssh anitha@anitha ip-to-unix-server`
- automatically connect, write simple bash shell wrap around your ssh connect command and do something, not suggested, you should use ssh password less login (aka public/private key)

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env bash
  ip=172.16.0.1   #replace 172.16.0.1 with your unix server's ip
  username=anitha #your ssh username
  password=anitha #your ssh password
  command=who     #what do you want to do with remote server
  arguments=      #arguments for your command
  expect -c 'spawn ssh $username@$ip ; expect password ; send "$password\n" ; interact'
  ```
- connect without typing password, you may need to use [SSH password less login](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/152)

Comment: `ssh $username@$password $ip $command $arguments` won't work (using standard openssh at least) - the password will be interpreted as a hostname, the ip as a command, and the command as the first argument. passwordless login is the way to go.

Comment: @RobinGreen But even with passwordless login you still need to type the passphrase to use the private key, no ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [sshpass](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/) if you *really* need to use non-interactive keyboard-interactive authentication (pun intended) or better switch to using pubkey-based authentication.

Note that passing the password in clear to the ssh client is very lame as the password gets exposed in the publicly-readable process list where it can be read by anyone. `sshpass` works around this problem by creating a pseudo-terminal and communicating with the ssh client using it, so at least the password is not exposed at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:**

```
jsmith@local-host$ [Note: You are on local-host here]

jsmith@local-host$ ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/jsmith/.ssh/id_rsa):[Enter key]
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): [Press enter key]
Enter same passphrase again: [Pess enter key]
Your identification has been saved in /home/jsmith/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/jsmith/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
33:b3:fe:af:95:95:18:11:31:d5:de:96:2f:f2:35:f9 jsmith@local-host
```

**Step 2:**
From Local-host, run this One liner for password less ssh connectivity.

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub | ssh useronanotherserver@anotherservername  'cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'
```

Comment: step2 : use ssh-copy-id anotherservername

Answer (score 0):

You should use `expect`, which is an extension of `tcl` that was made specifically for automating login tasks.

- Basic ssh login question: [could not able to spawn(ssh) using expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733060/could-not-able-to-spawnssh-using-expect)
- How to interact with the server programattically after you have established the session: [Expect Script to Send Different String Outputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086617/expect-script-to-send-different-string-outputs)

Comment: No! Using passwords like that is significantly less secure than using RSA keys. Of course, once you've done that then you hardly need to use the complexity of expect unless you're automating something nasty on the remote end (which `ls` definitely isn't…)

Comment: @Donal, remember that not everyone is a system administrator; automation is often required in lab environments where password security is not relevant.  Furthermore some devices (like those running Cisco IOS) **cannot use RSA key authentication**.  This is a simple example meant to illustrate a concept.  Add key authentication or whatever you like... then again, I know you are intimately familiar with Tcl, so "you" is whatever reader follows.

Comment: On most systems, adding an RSA key does not require any system privileges, just placing a public key in the right place (a one-time setup). Given that the result allows an admin to close off _all_ password-based logins (so absolutely defending against distributed cracks) I'm surprised that so many still resist it.

Comment: Cisco routers though… well, Cisco are a bunch of unhung scum in this respect; they charge a fortune for allowing you to log in securely, as its only supported on their high-end kit. I could rant rather a lot on the topic, but I don't think that really belongs on SO. It's more of a thing for slashdot…